# CSS Loading a Base64 Encoded Image as a Background URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Is it possible to load a Base64 encoded image as a `background-image: url("...")` but not expose the actual encoded string in the page source?

For instance, I have a Node API that when we GET request at `"/image"` it returns the serialised Base64 data.

```
res.json("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//Aw.....blah blah
```

Is it possible to load this on the frontend as a URL only? So the `background-image` displays the URL ONLY and the actual Base64 encoded text is not exposed in the frontend page source.

So if you right click and go to `inspect` it displays this:

```
.my-image {
    background-image: url("http://exampleapi.net:8080/image");
}
```

But not this:

```
.my-image {
    background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD.... etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is but not like that, since you are fetching only the base64 the server is not "serving" the file as static content, but in client-side a base64 can be converted into blob and generate and friendly `URI` if that works for you.

```
const base64ToBlobUrl = async (base64Data) => {
    const base64Response = await fetch(base64Data);
    const blob = await base64Response.blob();
    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return blobUrl;
}
```

This function will return a URI you can use in the `<img>` tag or in an in-line CSS background.